# What are the differences between Talend openstudio and Enterprise edition..??

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I really want the Differences between Talend open studio and Enterprise edition

What are the differences between Talend open studio and Enterprise edition..??
can you provide me in brief??

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. If you can't figure that out from their website, contact their support/sales team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used both products I can tell you there are two primary differences:

1. the paid version comes with the `Talend Administration Center` `(TAC)` which is a job scheduler.  It allows you to schedule jobs, setup dependencies, monitor and view logs.  It also allows you to centrally provision developer access and other roles (e.g. admin or operator to setup and monitor jobs).

The logging feature it is vital if you are seriously using the product for mission critical jobs.  You can setup recovery points in your job and if they fail re-run them in the TAC from the recovery point (a really cool feature).

2. It also allows you easily hook up to an `SVN` (or `GIT`) repository for version control, team collaboration, and code moves.  (I suspect you may be able to configure `SVN` access without enterprise version but it comes out of the box with enterprise).

There are some other more minor differences including a few components that are only available in the paid version.